# ValueError: class encoding field is specified without a type

Tags: python, nlp, altair

```py
dim_red = TruncatedSVD(n_components=2)
data_red = dim_red.fit_transform(tfidf)

scatter = alt.Chart(data_red,title="dimensionality reduction",height=400).mark_circle().encode(
    x='principal component 1', y='principal component 2', color=alt.Color(
        'class', scale=alt.Scale(scheme='blues')),tooltip=["class"]).interactive()
```

st.altair_chart(scatter)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error will generally arise when the encoding names (here `'principal component 1'` and/or `'principal component 2'`) do not match the names of any columns in the dataframe passed to the chart. Check the names of the columns in the dataframe, and make sure you're reproducing them correctly.